# Redshift- How to get max date

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to get a Max date without having to do a join back to the table and I'm wondering if that's possible. I'm trying to get the max of the version column and create a flag. Below is a table as an example on how the data is displayed after I execute the script below. But only version = 3 should have a flag value of 1 everything else should be 0

```
select e.id, e.version, e.version_type, q.status,
(case when e.version  = max(e.version) over (partition by e.id) then 1 else 0 end) as flag
from data.deployment_events e
join data.deployments d  on   e.id = d.id
```

| id | version | version_type | status | flag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | test | unopened | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | test | declined | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | test | unopened | 1 |
| 4 | 1 | test | completed | 1 |
| 5 | 1 | test | completed | 0 |
| 6 | 2 | test | opened | 0 |
| 7 | 3 | test | declined | 1 |

Actual result set expect or needed

| id | version | version_type | status | flag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | test | unopened | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | test | declined | 0 |
| 3 | 1 | test | unopened | 0 |
| 4 | 1 | test | completed | 0 |
| 5 | 1 | test | completed | 0 |
| 6 | 2 | test | opened | 0 |
| 7 | 3 | test | declined | 1 |

Comment: It seems you are missing a column that identifies what that version corresponds. Now you get one version per id. If you remove id, you get max(version) of the whole table, it does not sound like what you need. Please add the complete schema of both tables and some data samples.

Comment: Horaciux, After reading your comment, it made sense. I changed  found a unique identifier for each version and that fixed the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This query would determin the maximum version overall:

```
select e.id, e.version, e.version_type, q.status,
(case when e.version  = max(e.version) over () then 1 else 0 end) as flag
from data.deployment_events e
join data.deployments d  on   e.id = d.id;
```

Or something like this if you want to partition the data based on another column (x?):

```
select e.id, e.version, e.version_type, q.status,
(case when e.version  = max(e.version) over (partition by x) then 1 else 0 end) as flag
from data.deployment_events e
join data.deployments d  on   e.id = d.id;
```